# Differences between Proc and Lambda

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

Ruby has differences between Procs created via `Proc.new` and `lambda` (or the `->()` operator in 1.9). It appears that non-lambda Procs will splat an array passed in across the block arguments; Procs created via lambda do not.

```
p = Proc.new { |a,b| a + b}
p[[1,2]] # => 3

l = lambda { |a,b| a + b }
l[[1,2]] # => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

Does anyone have any insight into the motivations behind this behavior?

Comment: You may already know this, but this works: `l = lambda{ |(a,b)| a+b }; l[[1,2]] #=> 3`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are two main differences between lambdas and non-lambda `Proc`s:

1. Just like methods, lambdas return from themselves, whereas non-lambda `Proc`s return from the enclosing method, just like blocks.
2. Just like methods, lambdas have strict argument checking, whereas non-lambda `Proc`s have loose argument checking, just like blocks.

Or, in short: lambdas behave like methods, non-lambda `Proc`s behave like blocks.

What you are seeing there is an instance of #2. Try it with a block and a method in addition to a non-lambda `Proc` and a lambda, and you'll see. (Without this behavior, `Hash#each` would be a *real* PITA to use, since it *does* yield an array with two-elements, but you pretty much always want to treat it as two arguments.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Has#each / #sort was how I came across this in the first place.  I ended up using the following syntax to avoid the verbosity of Proc.new:

    ->((a,b)) { ... }