# Ruby - lambda vs. Proc.new

Tags: ruby, lambda, return, proc-object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a proc and a lambda in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740046/whats-the-difference-between-a-proc-and-a-lambda-in-ruby)

When  run this `Ruby` code:

```
def func_one
    proc_new = Proc.new {return "123"}
    proc_new.call
    return "456"
end

def func_two
    lambda_new = lambda {return "123"}
    lambda_new.call
    return "456"
end

puts "The result of running func_one is " + func_one
puts ""
puts "The result of running func_two is " + func_two
```

The result that I get is as follows:

```
The result of running func_one is 123

The result of running func_two is 456
```

As for `func_two`, where is the the value of the **first** `return`, that is, `123`?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of _[What's the difference between a proc and a lambda in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740046/whats-the-difference-between-a-proc-and-a-lambda-in-ruby)_; see also _[Differences between Proc and Lambda in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799964/differences-between-proc-and-lambda-in-ruby)_.

Comment: @Phrogz. Please check my question and the question in the thread you pointed to and see that my question is **not** a duplicate

Comment: I suppose that's a matter of opinion. You didn't ask the exact same question, but if you read the answer to that question you would have known the answer to your question.

Comment: Also see [Control flow differences between Ruby Procs and Lambdas](http://www.akshay.cc/blog/2010-02-14-control-flow-differences-between-ruby-procs-and-lambdas.html)

Comment: The more detailed answer is really here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new

Comment: I'm wondering if there's any compelling reason to use Procs over lambdas? They behave pretty weird, not what you would expect from anonymous functions.

Answer (score 38):

This is one of the main differences between Procs and lambdas.

A return in a Proc returns from its enclosing block/method, while a return in a lambda simply returns from the lambda.  When you call the lambda inside the func_two, it simply returns its value in place, which is not saved.

Read on Procs v. lambdas here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls

See duplicate SO question:
[Why does explicit return make a difference in a Proc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435743/why-does-explicit-return-make-a-difference-in-a-proc)

EDIT:

To further illustrate this difference, swap func_one and func_two for blocks and see what happens:

```
> begin; lambda { return 1 }.call end
1
> begin; Proc.new { return 1 }.call end
LocalJumpError: unexpected return
...
```

Answer (score 4):

In the proc, the `return "123"` is bubbling up and returning from the outer function, `func_one`. Therefore the second return statement is never encountered.

In the lambda, the `return "123"` is returning only from the lambda. You're not setting an variable to the return value of the lambda (when you do `lambda_new.call`, so the value is basically just thrown out. Then, the `return "456"` is called and returns from the function. If, instead of returning `"456"`, you returned `lambda_new.call`, the return value of `func_two` would be `"123"`.

Answer (score 0):

`123` is a value of `lambda_new.call` statement, but it is not used and not shows up.

Comment: What do you mean "it is not used"?  Your answer is not very clear.