# Proc.arity vs Lambda.arity

Tags: ruby

Why do proc and lambda return different values for arity?

e.g.

```
proc   { |x = 0| }.arity       #=> 0
lambda { |a = 0| }.arity       #=> -1
proc   { |x=0, y| }.arity      #=> 1
lambda { |x=0, y| }.arity      #=> -2
```

See: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html#method-i-arity

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per the docs you linked to:

> Returns the number of arguments that would not be ignored. If the block is declared to take no arguments, returns 0. If the block is known to take exactly n arguments, returns n. If the block has optional arguments, return -n-1, where n is the number of mandatory arguments. A proc with no argument declarations is the same a block declaring || as its arguments.

What the doc forgets to mention is that procs and lambda don't treat arguments precisely the same way e.g.:

```
>> p = proc { |a = 1, b| b }
=> #<Proc:0x007ff0091ef810@(irb):1>
>> l = lambda { |a = 1, b| b }
=> #<Proc:0x007ff0098099f8@(irb):2 (lambda)>
>> p.call
=> nil
>> l.call
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
    from (irb):2:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):4:in `call'
    from (irb):4
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Edit: The Ruby Programming Language, from O'Reilly, is the one with a tiny bit more details:

> 6.5.3 The Arity of a Proc
>
> The arity of a proc or lambda is the number of arguments it expects.
>   (The word is derived from the “ary” suffix of unary, binary, ternary,
>   etc.) Proc objects have an arity method that returns the number of
>   arguments they expect. For example:
>
> ```
> lambda{||}.arity # => 0. No arguments expected
> lambda{|x| x}.arity # => 1. One argument expected
> lambda{|x,y| x+y}.arity # => 2. Two arguments expected
> ```
>
> The notion of arity gets confusing when a Proc accepts an arbitrary
>   number of argu- ments in an *-prefixed final argument. When a Proc
>   allows optional arguments, the arity method returns a negative number
>   of the form -n-1. A return value of this form indicates that the Proc
>   requires n arguments, but it may optionally take additional arguments
>   as well. -n-1 is known as the one’s-complement of n, and you can
>   invert it with the ~ operator. So if arity returns a negative number
>   m, then ~m (or -m-1) gives you the number of required arguments:
>
> ```
> lambda {|*args|}.arity # => -1. ~-1 = -(-1)-1 = 0 arguments required
> lambda {|first, *rest|}.arity # => -2. ~-2 = -(-2)-1 = 1 argument required
> ```
>
> There is one final wrinkle to the arity method. In Ruby 1.8, a Proc
>   declared without any argument clause at all (that is, without any ||
>   characters) may be invoked with any number of arguments (and these
>   arguments are ignored). The arity method returns –1 to indicate that
>   there are no required arguments. This has changed in Ruby 1.9: a Proc
>   declared like this has an arity of 0. If it is a lambda, then it is an
>   error to invoke it with any arguments:
>
> ```
> puts lambda {}.arity # –1 in Ruby 1.8; 0 in Ruby 1.9
> ```

Edit 2: Stefan adds the precise reason they differ in a comment:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html#method-i-call

> For `procs` created using `lambda` or `->()` an error is generated if the wrong number of parameters are passed to a `Proc` with multiple parameters. For `procs` created using `Proc.new` or `Kernel.proc`, extra parameters are silently discarded.

Comment: From [`Proc#call`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html#method-i-call): *"For procs created using `lambda` or `->()` an error is generated if the wrong number of parameters are passed to a Proc with multiple parameters. For procs created using `Proc.new` or `Kernel.proc`, extra parameters are silently discarded."*

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned here:([Differences between Proc and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799964/differences-between-proc-and-lambda-in-ruby)), one of the primary differences between procs and lambda are that "Just like methods, lambdas have strict argument checking, whereas non-lambda Procs have loose argument checking, just like blocks."

Thus, since the arity is based on the number of *required* arguments, this will change between procs and lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the other 2 answers, my guess is that in #arity method is treading thin ice. For fixed number of ordered arguments, `#arity` used to be perfectly OK method. Then, when optional arguments were added, to stick with arity representation by a single integer, minus sign was exploited as a flag. But already, argument field information is being discarded, as eg. 1ary or 2ary `-> a, b=1 { a + b }` indicates same arity (-2) as `-> a, *b { a + b.sum }`, taking 1 to arbitrary number of arguments. After the change of `#arity` behavior in 1.9, another blow comes in 2.0, where named arguments are introduced, which go completely unnoticed by `#arity`. Again, there will be compulsory and optional named arguments, plus the possibility of collecting arbitrary number of them with hash splash `**`. I would expect `#arity` method to change its behavior again in the future...