# Iterate over array of arrays

Tags: ruby

This has been asked before, but I can't find an answer that works. I have the following code:

```
[[13,14,16,11],[22,23]].each do |key,value|
  puts key
end
```

It should in theory print:

```
0
1
```

But instead it prints:

```
13
22
```

Why does ruby behave this way?

Comment: @andy - I've added two references for further reading on the topic, in case you're interested in diving deeper into Ruby's behavior.

Comment: "It should ..." -- No, it should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does ruby behave this way?

It's because what *actually* happens internally, when `each` and other iterators are used with a block instead of a lambda, is actually closer to this:

```
do |key, value, *rest|
  puts key
end
```

Consider this code to illustrate:

```
p = proc do |key,value|
  puts key
end
l = lambda do |key,value|
  puts key
end
```

Using the above, the following will set `(key, value)` to `(13, 14)` and `(22, 23)` respectively, and the above-mentioned `*rest` as `[16, 11]` in the first case (with `rest` getting discarded):

```
[[13,14,16,11],[22,23]].each(&p)
```

In contrast, the following will spit an argument error, because the lambda (which is similar to a block except when it comes to arity considerations) will receive the full array as an argument (without any `*rest` as above, since the number of arguments is strictly enforced):

```
[[13,14,16,11],[22,23]].each(&l) # wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

To get the index in your case, you'll want `each_with_index` as highlighted in the other answers.

Related discussions:

- [Proc.arity vs Lambda.arity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986471/proc-arity-vs-lambda-arity/16986869#16986869)
- [Why does Hash#select and Hash#reject pass a key to a unary block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861502/why-does-hashselect-and-hashreject-pass-a-key-to-a-unary-block/20862285#20862285)

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want with `Array`'s `each_index' method which returns the index of the element instead of the element itself. See [Ruby's`Array` documentation][1](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-each_index) for more information.

Comment: This does not answer the question though. OP is asking *why*.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of arrays - known as a two-dimensional array.

In your loop, your "value" variable is assigned to the first array, `[13,14,16,11]`

When you attempt to `puts` the "value" variable, it only returns the first element, 13.

Try changing `puts value` to `puts value.to_s` which will convert the array to a string.

If you want every value, then add another loop block to your code, to loop through each element within the "value" variable.

```
[[1,2,3],['a','b','c']].each do |key,value|
  value.each do |key2,value2|
    puts value2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
[[13,14,16,11],[22,23]].each do |key,value|
```

before the first iteration is done it makes an assignment:

```
key, value = [13,14,16,11]
```

Such an assignment will result with `key` being 13 and `value` being 14. Instead you should use `each_with_index do |array, index|`. This will change the assignment to:

```
array, index = [[13,14,16,11], 0]
```

Which will result with `array` being [13,14,16,11] and `index` being `0`